# A Simple Graph: A Simple non-Hamiltonian Proof

Tags: graph-theory

How does one show that the following graph has no Hamiltonian cycle?

---

[image]

---

From N.S.'s comment I get that the problem really just reduces to the following simpler problem:

---

[image]

---

Actually, if you started at the top I guess that wouldn't really be the case... Maybe I should prove this using the $\wedge_{k=1}^np_i\implies q$ method:

---

[image]

---

Hmm... Maybe it can just be reduced to the following graph instead:

---

[image]

[image]

---

My own answer:

[image]

The subgraph $(a,b,c,d)$ is of critical importance here. Without doubt, a tracing along the graph must hit all of these points in the subgraph just mentioned either by exiting through $d$, and then re-entering through $b$ or *vice versa*. Either way, the tracer must make a choice upon re-entry to make a $(b,a)$-step or $(b,c)$-step, respectively $(d,a)$-step or $(d,c)$-step. Should the tracer take a $(b,a)$-step, respectively $(d,a)$-step, then the tracer will inevitably be trapped as proceeding to vertex $d$, respectively $b$, would mean the tracer hit that vertex twice. Now, if the tracer makes a $(b,c)$-step, respectively $(d,c)$-step, then the tracer will similarly be trapped as the proceeding vertex will have been traced upon twice. Thus, the graph cannot contain a Hamiltonian cycle.

---

Comment: The upper (or lower) triangle also immediately shows that there is no Hamiltonian cycle.

Comment: I don't know if it makes it easier, but you could reduce it to a 3-SAT problem and show that all clauses can't be satisfied.

Comment: Here, the central line must be crossed.

Comment: You don't need a start point. The `triangle`` at the top must be part of a cycle, same for the `triangle`` at the bottom. But a cycle cannot contain a strictly smaller cycle.

Comment: Just color the edges which pass through the vertices of degree 2 with red, then you`ll see the solution.....

Comment: What do you mean? Going anti-clockwise?

Comment: @Trancot Check the edit to my answer.

Comment: @N.S. Check the edit to my proposition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** Assume by contradiction that the graph has a Hamiltonian cycle. Then the cycle must contain the four vertices of degree $2$ and there is only one way to visit each of those. Those give you 8 edges in the cycle, but for obvious reasons those 8 edges are not part of one cycle....

**Added** I argued above that the red edges below must be part of the Hamiltonian cycle. Then the Hamiltonian cycle would contain two smaller $4$-cycles, which is impossible (a cycle cannot contain a smaller cycle as a subgraph).

[image: Pic]

Comment: I bet there is a clever way to reduce this substantially...

Comment: Something like, all four points on a circle can't be hit with only two alternating exits without hitting a point twice...

Comment: @Trancot What do you mean reduce? The cycle must contain the 4 cycle at the top and the 4 cycle at the bottom. How can a cycle contain two cicles?

Comment: @Trancot If you have problems seeing the solution, which should be obvious from my hint, please label the vertices on your figure so I can refer to them....

Comment: I see what you're saying, but why can't I show it for the reduced graph?

Comment: No! Because this graph requires that the master tracer traces across the center line necessarily because points there must be hit.

Comment: See my most recent edit...